# Asp.net Identity with Code First in Asp.net MVC application using class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to implement **Identity Authentication** using class library with code first in my *asp.net MVC* application.
At first I created test project with default selection "Individual User Accounts"
Using default templates with identity i found It creates some of the default files/classes like 
`IdentityModel.cs`, `IdentityConfig.cs`(in APP_Start) & `Startup.cs`(partial class with anothe file in APP_Start Startup.Auth.cs),
`AccountViewModel.cs`, `ManageViewModel.cs` .

After that I searched for how to use identity related classes in Class Library, and using suggestions moved
all of above in class library project Names `TestLib`.

I have put `IdentityModel.cs`, `IdentityConfig.cs` in Model folder in `TestLib` and Startup in root of `TestLib` and change respective references in my web project.
I have removed OwinStartupAttribute from `Startup.cs` in web project and added `OwinStartupAttribute` to Startup.cs in `TestLib`.
And all seems to be working well also code first, but here I have some questions whether I am doing things correctly or not.

> 1) Is it OK to have `Startup.cs` in class library?
>
> 2) At now I have other models for my database in "ApplicationDbContext"
>   class, which creates table correctly in database.

So

1.Is it OK to use ApplicationDbContext instead of my `CustomContext` & can I 
    use this class library with my other application like some
    windows application which do not use identity?  **OR**

2. Should I keep separate context?  **OR**
3. Is it possible to remove `ApplicationDbContext` and use my `CustomContext`?